# How to set up remote ip for Charles

Tags: charles-proxy

> when i use charles;it shows
>   Denying access to Charles from /58.218.199.54;
>   I find this configuration in the config file (.charles.config)   ;

```
<accessControlConfiguration>
    <ipRanges/>
</accessControlConfiguration>
```

> how can i change it

Comment: Ain't there no official docs? Gotta be in there.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Proxy menu in Charles and choose Access Control Settings. You'll find you can add IP ranges to the list that are allowed to access Charles.

There is also a checkbox "Prompt to allow unauthorized connections" which, if ticked, will mean you'll see an alert when unauthorized connections are attempted and you can add them to the ACL straight from the alert.

Maybe at some point you ticked a "don't show me this again" on an ACL alert, if that is unticked?

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for the answer to this for days!